# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError in com.jrefinery.chart.JFreeChartInfo

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jfreechart

I am working jfreeChart and facing this issue when i call this.

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createAreaXYChart(str_chartLabel,str_xAxisLabel, str_yAxisLabel, xyDataset, true);
```

**It throws this Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.jrefinery.ui.about.ProjectInfo.name from class com.jrefinery.chart.JFreeChartInfo
    at com.jrefinery.chart.JFreeChartInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jrefinery.chart.JFreeChart.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jrefinery.chart.ChartFactory.createAreaXYChart(Unknown Source)
    at jFreeChart.ImageUtils.createImageByXyChart(myClassName.java:37)
    at jFreeChart.ImageUtils.main(myClassName.java:103)
```

Comment: `jfreechart-1.0.19` and `jcommon-1.0.23` are current and compatible with each other.

Comment: jcommon-0.6.4 and jfreechart-0.9.3 are also compatible. although they are not current versions but they are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly why but as this exception says that: [IllegalAccessError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html)

> Thrown if an application attempts to access or modify a field, or to call a method that it does not have access to.
> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

In your case `com.jrefinery.chart.JFreeChartInfo.<init>` try to access the `com.jrefinery.ui.about.ProjectInfo.name` property which is not accessible to it.

So try to use older or newer version of `jrefinery` library.

Comment: yes it was quite odd. Exception and Error should be differentiated properly.

Answer (score 1):

Few days back I also faced this issue. By using compatible versions of JFreeChart and JCommon I got rid of this issue.